# c++ libcurl fails to access, command line works

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm trying to access a web service from curl with a TLSv1.2 connection.
I'm able to access the service sucessfully via the command line with:

```
  curl -l --tlsv1.2 -E client.pem -v https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation/sgx/v1/sigrl/00000010
```

But when trying it in C++ with libcurl I receive the error:

```
 error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

This is a short version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation/sgx/v1/sigrl/00000010");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./client.pem");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return (int)res;
}
```

Do I have to set any further options?

Version of `curl`:

```
 curl --version
 curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

Version of `libcurl`:

```
 ii  libcurl3:amd64                              7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2        
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64                       7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2                        
ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64                  7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2
```

Comment: The following line looks suspicious:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./client.pem");

Is client.pem certificate supposed to be a CA certificate to validate server's certificate? From its name I'd assume it is some client certificate, not a CA.

Basically you can try disabling curl SSL validation and see if it works:
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: Are you sure that you are linking your program against the same versions of libcurl and libssl that the curl command-line utility uses?

Comment: I have tried the suggested option but I still receive the same error...

Comment: @zwol I've updated the versions for curl and libcurl

Comment: @wasp256 Those are the versions of various things that you have installed, but without further information you have not told me whether they are the versions of things that are actually used by either the `curl` in your PATH or the linkage of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the problem is that you're incorrectly using your client certificate as you set it to be used as a CA for validating server-side certificate with

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./client.pem");
```

This doesn't match how client.pem is used in the command line where it is passed with -E flag.

```
-E, --cert <certificate[:password]>
          (SSL) Tells curl to use the specified client certificate file when getting a file with HTTPS, FTPS or another SSL-based  protocol.
```

Try to remove that line and use the following lines instead:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "./client.pem");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

If this works, **you should remove the line setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0** and experiment with setting proper CA to validate server-side certificate.

Comment: Very, very tempted to downvote you for suggesting turning off peer verification *at all*.  Odds are it never gets turned on again...

Comment: @zwol that is why the last sentence suggests removing that option once the original issue is resolved. Agreed this should be emphasized.